# How to rebase one Git repository onto another one?

Tags: git, merge, repository, rebase

I had one Git repository (A) which contains the development of a project until a certain point. Then I lost the USB stick this repo A was on. Luckily I had a backup of the latest commit, so I could create a new repository (B) later where I imported the latest project's state and continue development.
Now I recovered that lost USB stick, so I have two Git repositories.

I think I just have to rebase repo B onto repo A somehow, but I have no idea how to do that, maybe using fetch/pull and rebase?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If A and B are not the same repo (you created B by using the latest working copy you had), you have to use a [graft](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint) to pretend that they have common history.

Let’s assume you’ve added A as a remote for B as per [VonC’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2428224), and the repo looks like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
~/B$ git tnylog 
* 6506232 (HEAD, master) Latest work on B
* 799d6ae Imported backup from USB stick
~/B$ git tnylog A/master
* 33b5b16 (A/master) Head of A
* 6092517 Initial commit
```

Create a graft telling the root of B that its parent is the head of A:

```
echo '799d6aeb41095a8469d0a12167de8b45db02459c 33b5b16dde3af6f5592c2ca6a1a51d2e97357060' \
 >> .git/info/grafts
```

Now the two histories above will appear as one when you request the history for B. Making the graft permanent is a simple `git filter-branch` with no arguments. After the filter-branch, though, you aren’t on any branch, so you should `git branch -D master; git checkout -b master`.

---

<sup>1</sup> `git tnylog` = `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`

Comment: +1 for taking care of the "other scenario" were A and B differ completely in commit history.

Comment: This was a brilliant help; did absolutely what I wanted with a minimum of fuss. Thank you!

Comment: I just used the subtree-merge approach to stitch several repositories into one. I successively failed at the attempt to rebase them one over the other. Using graft points, I've now been able to stitch them onto a single development timeline, thanks!

Comment: +1 By the way, I edited your answer to reflect what your  `git-tnylog` does (I was puzzled and took me a while until I found it was an alias of yours: ['Pimped tnylog a bit'](https://github.com/jleedev/dotfiles/commit/dc70a0bbef6ab6c7afabd49d6b917adca66e7bf5))

Comment: How would you push this to a remote? Say I host my B on bitbucket and want to push this. Simply (--force) pushing a new commit to bitbucket doesn't (appear) to add the history of A to  the the remote bitbucket.

Comment: I already tried the command `git filter-branch 33b5b16dde3af6f5592c2ca6a1a51d2e97357060..HEAD` from [link](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) but then I can't push anymore since I get the error that the remote has unresolved deltas (`remote: fatal: pack has 50 unresolved deltas`).

Comment: Update: after an hour of googling and using the rebasing option from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450131/how-to-properly-push-one-git-repository-over-another-on-codebasehq), I managed to create something which could be pushed to a new bare repo.

Comment: @PimJager (or anyone else with the same query), see: [How to push a “git replace --graft”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489421/how-to-push-a-git-replace-graft).

Comment: Related: [How do git grafts and replace differ? (Are grafts now deprecated?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800692/how-do-git-grafts-and-replace-differ-are-grafts-now-deprecated).

Comment: I'm getting an error "too many pending edits on SO" so I am going to suggest two changes here. 1. remove mention of author's personal alias "tnylog" and use the standard git command line from the footnote. 2. "Make the graft permanent by running `git filter-branch` with no arguments." As written, the sentence is both confusing and a bit judgmental of those who are unfamiliar with 'filter-branch'.

Answer (score 46):

If A and B are the same repo (the first SHA1 are common), you can:

- declare A as a remote for B: `git remote add A /path/to/A`
- `git fetch A` to [update all remote A branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch) on the B repo
- `git checkout dev` (on B, where you are developing)
- `git rebase A/devBranch` to replay B (i.e. what you develop or re-develop from your backup) on top of `A/devBranch` (the development you lost). A bit like this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457248/how-do-i-re-play-my-commits-of-a-local-git-repo-on-top-of-a-project-i-forked-on/1458069#1458069).

The last step allows you to sync your dev with the one you lost.
But actually, once you have fetch from A, you are done: B now contains the "*all*" history (the one you lost and your current work)

Comment: Thanks, seems to work, just have to resolve some conflicts during the merge/rebase now :)

Comment: @kroimon: conflicts were inevitable, I suppose, since you were re-developing in B some part of the code committed in A.

Comment: I ended up in a detached HEAD, and had to reference this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25670296/1807668

Comment: @AlisonS I agree: the rebase command was incorrect. If you have checked out `dev`, all you need is `git rebase A/devBranch` in order to replay `dev` on top of `A/devBranch`. I have edited the answer.

Comment: This worked well for me without A and B having a common first SHA1. I did an interactive rebase and dropped some initial commits.

Comment: This is the real answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

### 2021 Update

`git filter-branch` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91243b019ddba5248f0fde319bc75e4e2b5602b0) since Git 2.24 (Q4 2019). Instead, for the scenario where A and B are not the same repo, you can use [`git replace --graft <commit> <parent>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace#Documentation/git-replace.txt---graftltcommitgtltparentgt82308203).

See:

- ["How do I combine several Git repositories without breaking file history?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938676/6732127)
- ["Git commands that could break/rewrite the history"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6732127)

Comment: But nevertheless `git filter-branch` still does not have a full replacement. The declared official replacement `git filter-repo` still can not fully replace it because of revealed issues: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/465 https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/473

Comment: `because of revealed issues` I suggest anybody reading that sentence to check for themselves the discussion on these "revealed issues" (at least the last messages in #473). Looks like `git filter-repo` works fine if one knows what it does (like everything else git I suppose)

Comment: @soxsupportsthemods corrupted repo and unexpected results definitely is not "works fine"

Comment: @Andry from the issue discussions seems like the "corrupted repo and unexpected results" are just the way you see the normal output of that tool. That's why I added " if one knows what it does", which you left out of the quote. I won't argue those issues with you but again I suggest anybody interested in using it to read for themselves those discussions, because the author explains in great detail (and with lots of patience) why those "revealed issues" are actually the intended effects of using the tool.

Comment: @soxsupportsthemods This is not "intended effects", this is undocumented behaviour has found by tests. If you want to hit that by you prod repo, then go ahead, I won't argue either.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, start by making a working clone of repo A.

Then simply pull into it from B and merge. You might prefer to create a new branch, pull onto it, then merge the two branches. You might also need a forcing flag; I've done things like this in Mercurial (grafting two apparently-unrelated repositories together) and it needs "-f".