# How to combine two separate unrelated Git repositories into one with single history timeline

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two unrelated (not sharing any ancestor check in) Git repositories, one is a super repository which consists a number of smaller projects (Lets call it repository A). Another one is just a makeshift local Git repository for a smaller project (lets call it repository B). Graphically, it would look like this

```
A0-B0-C0-D0-E0-F0-G0-HEAD (repo A)
A0-B0-C0-D0-E0-F0-G0-HEAD (remote/master bare repo pulled & pushed from repo A)
A1-B1-C1-D1-E1-HEAD (repo B)
```

Ideally, I would really like to merge repo B into repo A with a single history timeline. So it would appear that I originally started project in repo A. Graphically, this would be the ideal end result

```
A0-A1-B1-B0-D1-C0-D0-E0-F0-G0-E1-H(from repo B)-HEAD (new repo A)
A0-A1-B1-B0-D1-C0-D0-E0-F0-G0-E1-H(from repo B)-HEAD (remote/master bare repo pulled & pushed from repo A)
```

I have been doing some reading with submodules and subtree (Pro Git is a pretty good book by the way), but both of them seem to cater solution towards maintaining two separate branch with sub module being able to pull changes from upstream and subtree being slightly less headache. Both solution require additional and specialized git commands to handle check ins and sync between master and sub tree/module branch. Both solution also result in multiple timelines (with subtree you even get 3 separate timelines when using --squash).

The closest solution from SO seems to talk about "[graft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428137/how-to-rebase-one-git-repository-onto-another-one)", but is that really it? The goal is to have a single unified repository where I can pull/push check-ins, so that there are no more repo B, just repo A in the end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you merge two git repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant No, I reject subtree & submodule solution as the scenario is not the same

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you do it like this:

1. git remote add [repo b]
2. git fetch//get the repo b into repo a
3. due to you want to keep the history like this: 
   A0-A1-B1-B0-D1-C0-D0-E0-F0-G0-E1-H(from repo B)-HEAD (new repo A)
   you can first select the A0 as a start point, after that, use git cherry-pick one by one.

Hope this is useful for you.

Br,
Tim

Comment: Combined your solution along with this guide @ http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/, it works!

Comment: you can cherry pick the full range using 
   "git cherry-pick startHash^..lastHash"
and use 
   "git cherry-pick --continue"
after each manual merge.

Answer (score 8):

I did something similar (merge history from B into A) like this:

1. go to your repo A
2. `git fetch <ref to your repo B> master:new-branch-on-A` (so, you have copied master branch of B into a new branch 'new-branch-on-A' into your repo A.
3. `git checkout new-branch-on-A`
4. `git rebase master` (you rebase the new-branch-on-A with the master branch)
5. resolve conflicts if there are any
6. `git checkout master`
7. `git merge new-branch-on-A`
8. `git branch -d new-branch-on-A`
9. Done :), your histories are merged. I think all commits from A are before commit from B in the new history (`git rebase -i` is your friend if needed).

Answer (score 5):

I believe the correct and most straightforward way of merging two unrelated histories is done with plain `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories​`.

- [`git-merge` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)
- [Step by step instructions & source of edited snippet, below](https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/git-combine/)

> [From within the "new home" repository:] To combine the two repositories, first add the second repository as a remote to the first. Then, run `git fetch` to fetch its branch information:
>
> ```
> git remote add repo-to-insert ../local/path/to/other/repo
> git fetch repo-to-insert
> ```
>
> Then, with the remote set up, merge the second repository’s history into the first using the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag:
>
> ```
> git merge repo-to-insert/branch-to-merge --allow-unrelated-histories
> Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
>  two.txt | 0
>  1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
>  create mode 100644 two.txt
> ```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding more details of the steps involved, such as `git remote add` and `git fetch` to get both histories into a single repo before doing the `git merge`.