# Merge a Git repository with a sub directory of remote Git

Tags: git, merge, subdirectory, git-remote

I have a Git repository and everything is on root, but on remote git repository the desired content is one level deep (there are three types of folder 1-git folders 2-DemoProject 3.some-other-folder-i-have-no-concern). How to merge these two together. Even though they are completely disconnected but i have found the way to merge the disconnected repository but this level thing isn't working.

```
LocalBranch(DemoProject)
     -(git folders)
     -Content1
     -Content2

Remote Branch
      -(git folders)  
      -DemoProject
         -Content1
         -Content2
       -Some Folder
```

Comment: It would help if the remote repo would split DemoProject into its own repo and reference it through a submodule entry. Do you have the possibility to split that remote repo in two? Or don't you have any access/control over that remote repo?

Comment: i have updated the question but no its going to be same. some documents and old stuff is there too.

Answer (score 0):

One way would to:

- clone the remote repo
- reorganize (in a dedicated branch) its content in order to reflect your own repo
- push that dedicated branch

Then, following "[How to combine two separate unrelated Git repositories into one with single history timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9781995/6309)", you can combine the history of your repo on top of the remote repo (which, on that special branch, contains the right structure).

Comment: but when you push it will change the remote structure as well, won't it.. That we can't do

Comment: @Waqas it will change the structure on a dedicated branch only, so it shouldn't have any visible impact.