# Moving git repo to an another one

Tags: git, repository, branch, move

I have two git repositories, each one with two branches, named "master" and "release".
Let me call them repo1 and repo2.
I would like to move the content of repo2 into repo1 preserving its history, moving the history of branch master into the branch of the same name, and the history of branch release into the branch of the same name.
Then, when I checkout a branch, that must include the content of both repositories.
Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255480/merge-git-repositores