# Git push all parent commits to the remote (ie rewrite remote history)

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

A bit of context:
I recently migrated from CVS to Git using cvsimport. There is now a common (bare) repository, managed by gitolite, where people push their local changes.
I then discovered that many tags from the old CVS history were not perfectly imported. I could fix that by re-doing the migration from CVS using cvs2git (locally), and grafted the branches' heads of my first repo onto the new tree given by cvs2git (still locally). I now have a complete tree with a nicer history than before, where the heads of all the branches have the same hash as what is currently on the remote (I used grafts and filter-branch, as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2428339/1005470)

What I would now like to do is to push those changes to the remote. Of course, `git push` returns that everything is up-to-date: I don't know **how to push a re-written history**.
Because the refs match, `git push -f` also returns that everything is up-to-date.

Moreover, I would of course like that other developers barely notice that something has changed. They should just see an updated history next time they pull (I'm also OK if they have to re-clone). I am assuming that they have not based any work on commits prior to the branches' heads (I am aware that it would otherwise be a big mess).

Edit: to clarify, here is (an extract of) the output of `git rev-list HEAD` on both repositories. The commit in bold is the point where I did the graft. I would like to overwrite everything below that point in the remote by what I have in the local repository.

> *Local repo*:
>      **fff881c238fff8b0057be8dab494ec5a6aa181d9**
>       ac513b5596cca48dd885a969fdcc4a2b49e507d0
>       1b199d8e4ac29e4bd39ff96059031cf9b1390609
>       427837c98a14f28bc2e5d91fcf89e954b3bb3e77
>       0d9e58cc4f6a0107c718c689e24353d4ce59ab8c
>       ....
>
> *Remote repo*:
>       6ad634da6e5acda43e6cf0919e8f4994c08ac862
>       bd32b7c9b0ae4faea51720b98586f89972b52e58
>       3778ce4ff85f269e2287d57c7aec3ecefabc135a
>       d3c343f3498d1d82b680be2ffc2c5e05c14a3d4c
>       a5d200b99f31a005cc8312d0a23a79d4014a2156
>       8b90afbbb06bea062d26b520c42c068ef96e5db7
>       **fff881c238fff8b0057be8dab494ec5a6aa181d9**
>       19cf091efb12413027941ac893ea8d503fea415e
>       efbed577d5986beef45ba0f9a2560f4b1ca120fc
>       bbec686e3389abe0679672a3d71c236b98ffc111
>       5b56665e48b3af51a25d0c9d2342d04e730aaa16
>       2ce095b0ed92f22baf74e728bda07bfded5a4e7b
>       ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your local branches are not set up to track the remote branches.

You will need to either set remote tracking in your branches (check the `--set-upstream` option for the `branch` command) and then do a bare `git push`; or push each branch individually, specifying the branch names in the push command: `git push --set-upstream <remote> <remote-branch-name>` for each branch, while having that branch checked out.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. The branches already do track the right remote branches. I triple checked and did the explicit "git push --set-upstream" as you suggested but I always get the "Everything up-to-date" message.

Comment: you can `git fetch origin` and then `git branch -va`. The latter will list all of the branch references your repo knows about, with each head commit id. You can then compare the local and remote heads. From git's response to your push command it looks like they are already the same.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The heads are all the same, and this is what I want. Everything else is different, though - and this is what I would like to push to the remote. Effectively rewriting all the history of the remote, except for the heads.

Comment: what do you mean by "everything else is different"? If you change any of the commits leading up to a branch head then that branch head's commit id *will* change, there is no way around that... It seems like you just imported all of your "old" commits into this new repo and the branch heads were reset; your local commits and branches are now unreachable and will eventually be removed.

Comment: No, I did a graft between the old heads (that I want to keep) and the new parents of these heads (that I want to change). The branches' heads were not reset. Of course, the commits from the old history were destroyed when I filtered the branches. This is what I did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2428339/1005470