# Rebase a branch that has been copied from somewhere else not cloned from the main branch (Git)

Tags: git, github, gitlab

if I have this issue in git that I started develop a feature branch
(red line) that was copied from somewhere else and not being cloned from the main developing branch (main purpose is to keep the history of the main branch in other word to rewrite the history)

[image]

Is there a way to rebase the changes to the original branch to keep the history of original branch, or there are another option to do this purpose? I am afraid to run into a continuous errors that can not be solved.

**SOLVED:** using rebase and manual solving of the conflicts, git has rewritten the history of the main branch and added them to my feature branch, I have cloned my feature branch as new development main branch.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use the [git replace --graft](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace#Documentation/git-replace.txt---graftltcommitgtltparentgt82308203) feature to add a parent to an existing commit.

**For a commit that has no parents at the moment**, the command is:

`git replace --graft <HASH_OF_1ST_FEATURE_BRANCH_COMMIT> <HASH_OF_MAIN_BRANCH_COMMIT_YOU_WANT_TO_BRANCH_FROM>`

Git will create a graft file and you will **display** the desired history (but at the moment no history is re-written).

**But it will be local to your repository and there must be [pushed explicitely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42494208/717372)**

The downside is that some tools (like GitHub) doesn't support it.

So the best thing is then to rewrite history with built-in `git filter-branch` (or even the recommended [filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#re-grafting-history) ) using the command:

```
git filter-branch HEAD
```

Then you could force push the rewritten history.

Note: the graft feature of git takes advantage of the fact that each git commit is a snapshot of **all** the directories and files and so any commit in the past could be added as a parent of another commit as git is calculating a diff between these commits for display only when requested.

Comment: As an alternative, even though it was not what was explicitly asked for, there's the `--allow-unrelated-histories` [option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---allow-unrelated-histories) for `git merge`. That's not a rebase, but it could be a simpler way to join histories, depending on the context.