# moving commits from unrelated repository in git, git-p4

Tags: git, perforce

I've been learning git and git-p4 and have ended up in a situation where I can't 'git-p4 submit' anymore; patches don't cleanly apply.

I can always re-clone the p4 depot and copy my new changes over the top and 'git-p4 submit', but I'd like to maintain my commit history in the new git repository.  Given that the old and new repositories start from an identical state, is there a way of moving commits from the old to the new, even thought the new wasn't 'git clone'd from the old?

Answer (score 1):

You could try and look into **[git grafts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161928/what-are-git-info-grafts-for)**, to see if you can merge the two history (one large in your git repo, and the new short one, from a new p4 clone)

You have more details in the question "[How do I prepend history to a git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220557/how-do-i-prepend-history-to-a-git-repo)"