# How to git svn fetch older history?

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn

I have checkout'ed svn repo through git, but not from the first svn commit.
Now I would like to extend the history a little back into past. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could follow the possibilities mentioned by [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski) in [How do I prepend history to a git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220557/how-do-i-prepend-history-to-a-git-repo)

Basically, you import again your SVN repo with a larger commit range, then merge the two Git repo together.

Answer (score 2):

Not with your current history. But you can checkout the full history from SVN again and then rebase or merge your changes on that new branch.

Now your first commit (A) has no parent (or a parent of 00000 or something like that). If you get more, older commits, one of them will be the new parent of A. Although both refer to the same content, they will have different parents and therefore different commit hashes (eg. A and A'). You will end up with a parallel branch.

Then you can take whatever extra commits you made locally and rebase or merge them to the new history.